# What does the accessibilityLabel property do in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning to react native and found the **accessibilityLabel** property in the **Button** component. Can anyone tell what does the **accessibilityLabel** property do in android? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility#accessibilitylabel-ios-android) for the complete description about the accessibilityLabel property.

It is generally used by assistive applications, so they can provide this information to users with disabilities. So you should use an intuitive value for this property, e.g. "Login" or "Play".

Comment: I have checked this documentation but didn't get any idea why to use this property?

Comment: So, you mean the text will be spoken by the phone for the people who cannot hear?

Comment: Yes, the assistive software will read the label for people who cannot see, or are partially impaired visually.

Comment: what does it do exactly natively? Does it set the contentDesc on android?